# how to show image after store image into sd card on android

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

In my application I want download image from server and store this into **SD card**.
I write below code and I can download and store on SD card.
But After store image into SD card not show into Gallery !

**My codes :**

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp/Wallpaper");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/MyApp/Wallpaper/");
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/MyApp/Wallpaper/"), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            showReturnMessage("Message","Successfully saved :) ",R.color.alertSuccess);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can it ?

Comment: You are #12345 with this problem. You have to invoke the media scanner to tell the media store about your new image file. Google... Alternatively reboot your device and see that the Gallery knows youf file.

Comment: `how to show image after store image into sd card on android`. Bad subject when you mean that it does not show in the gallery.

Comment: @greenapps, I know when reboot phone show images, but I don't reboot phone. I want without reboot phone, can you help me and send to me code? please

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your gallery every time you save an image. Try calling this method after you save it:

```
static public void notifyMediaScannerService(Context context, String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { path }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but what is new `ContentValues(3);` ? why you set 3 ? and not work me again :(

Comment: @BoboGoooool the initial size of the set of values. What is your Android version?

Comment: android 7 . can you help me? please

Comment: hey can you help me? please

Comment: how can I use you new update code? can you help to me with my above codes? because I am amateur and really need your help. please